# Laravel multiple table join: how to join two table with all columns and except one column

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have two table with more than 100 columns .
I want to join two table with all columns except one column .

---

$agents = agents::join(‘cities’,’cities.id’,’city_id)->select(‘agents.*’,’cities.name as city’)->get();

---

.
.
Now join all agents table but i don’t want egents.user_id

Comment: can you explain a bit more what you want

Comment: I have two table and join that . But don’t want one column from one table in my join

Comment: Table have a user_id and i dont want send user-id in join

Comment: Why have you tagged MySQL, SQL Server and SQLite? They are all different RDBMS?

Comment: Yes but all about databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using make hidden array in model is good,hide your column from serialization where you need with makeHidden function like this :

```
$agents = agents::where('your query')->get();
$agents ->makeHidden(['user_id']);
return response()->json($agents);
```

I hope you enjoy it

Answer (score 1):

May I know the content of the table ?
Like example?

If laravel, I would go like:

```
DB::table('users')
->select('users.*','profiles.photo', 'profiles.one_by_one')
->join('profiles','profiles.id','=','users.id')
->where(['something' => 'something', 'otherThing' => 'otherThing'])
->get();
```

You can just unselect the column you don't want to join.

OR

You can try this

```
DB::table('users')
->select('users.*','profiles.*')

->except('users.id')
OR
->exclude('users.id')

->join('profiles','profiles.id','=','users.id')
->where(['something' => 'something', 'otherThing' => 'otherThing'])
->get();
```

Please to test it

OR

In your model laravel, add this to the model you don't want to see certain column.

```
protected $hidden = array('column_you_dont_want_to_see');
```

Comment: From this example i want all users table except (for example) phone columns

Comment: How about you add this into your model?

```
protected $hidden = array('column_you_dont_want_to_see');

```

Comment: In laravel if i use this model we don’t see this any where